# Print issue in internet explorer, when exported to xps file

Tags: xps

I am using following code to print the div element -

```
                <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                <head>
                    <title>Untitled Page</title>

                    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                        function printDiv(divID) {
                            //Get the HTML of div
                            var divElements = document.getElementById(divID).innerHTML;
                            //Get the HTML of whole page
                            var oldPage = document.body.innerHTML;

                            //Reset the page's HTML with div's HTML only
                            document.body.innerHTML = 
                              "<html><head><title></title></head><body>" + 
                              divElements + "</body>";

                            //Print Page
                            window.print();

                            //Restore orignal HTML
                            document.body.innerHTML = oldPage;


                        }
                    </script>

                </head>
                <body>
                    <form id="form1" runat="server">
                    <div id="printablediv" style="width: 100%; background-color: Blue; height: 200px">
                        Print me I am in 1st Div
                    </div>
                    <div id="donotprintdiv" style="width: 100%; background-color: Gray; height: 200px">
                        I am not going to print
                    </div>
                    <input type="button" value="Print 1st Div" onclick="javascript:printDiv('printablediv')" />
                    </form>
                </body>`enter code here`
                </html>
```

I am using this code in an jquery popup box, the print seems to be fine in all the browsers except internet explorer where the file is exported to xps file, this print file includes not only the contents from popup window but also the page contents which overlaps the popup contents. Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this issue?